# Unable to load data from on prem to Synapse using polybase/Copy Method

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake, polybase

ADF, ADLS and Synapse all are in private end points and we are able to extract data from on prem and load into synapse using Bulk insert method in ADF copy Activity. But when using polybase/Copy method  the copy after staging fails .It copies till staged area but fails to load into actual DB. I can see ADF has Blob data contributor Role to ADLS. But still fails with the access related issue. sharing screenshots for ref

we are using dedicated Integration runtime for Synapse and ADLS. I dont understand what else access it needs

[Using Poybase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbh3R.png)

Comment: can you add images of pipeline for better understanding

Comment: I cant add images of pipeline...Since its a secure nw...But The Pipeline just has a copy activity and source is a on prem Sql server, target is Synapse .I tired both COpy Method and Polybase .

Answer (score 0):

The Error `PolybaseNoADLSGen2Permission` is because of the Synapse workspace or data warehouse has not proper permissions on the ADLS.

To resolve this, **Grant `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role to Azure Synapse Identity on Azure Storage (ADLS)**

From the Azure Portal, navigate to your storage account,

Go to Access Control (IAM) >> Select Add Role Assignment >> add Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the Managed Identity created of Azure Synapse Under **System-assigned managed identity**, select **Synapse workspace**, and then select a workspace. You can also use the object ID or workspace name (as the managed-identity name) to find this identity.

[image]